# Bash create .tar.gz on Solaris

Tags: bash, gzip, solaris, archive, tar

I'm writting a bash script, which should create a .tar.gz archive from specified directory including file structure. This is a homework and I need it to work on Solaris system my school uses. That means I can't use tar like this

```
tar xvzf archive.tar.gz ./
```

because this system uses some older version of tar without -z option. I use it like this

```
tar xvf - ./ | gzip > archive.tar.gz
```

It works fine except a strange fact, that when I examine contents of the archive, it contains itself (in other words, it contains "archive.tar.gz"). How can I prevent this?

Comment: `tar` on Solaris has an argument `X Exclude.  Use the  exclude-filename  argument  as  a file  containing  a  list  of named files (or direc-tories) to be excluded from the tarfile  when  using the  key  letters  c, x, or t.`. Create a file in /tmp which contains the name of the resulted file. Or create the zipped tarfile in /tmp and move it if created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

This works: 
    tar cvf -  | gzip > archive.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Thing is, that file named "archive.tar.gz" is created immediately when you run your command. Meaning, before gzip is called. It's just blank file, but it is in directory. To prevent including it into resulting archive, you can try to modify your script in one of following ways:

1. `tar xvf - ./ | gzip > ../archive.tar.gz`
2. `tar xvf - {path_to_dir_you_want_to_compress_files_from} | gzip > archive.tar.gz`

Sadly, I can't check if either of this scripts works, because I don't have Solaris anywhere. Please, let me know if any of that works.

Comment: first one works not exactly the way I need it. It fixes the problem but the archive is created in an "upper" directory (sry, dont know the right word for that xD).
The second one works well and I guess I should have mentioned that but obviously the problem occurs only if I compress working directory and your suggestion doesn't fix that (maybe I just don't get it)

Comment: Not working for me, it was needed to change `tar xvf` to `tar cvf`